# Explanation of Verse 6, Surah Yusuf [12:6]

Tags: quran, tafseer, arabic, surat-yusuf, prophet-yusuf

Verse 5 of Surah Yusuf states:

> قَالَ يَـٰبُنَىَّ لَا تَقۡصُصۡ رُءۡيَاكَ عَلَىٰٓ إِخۡوَتِكَ
>   فَيَكِيدُواْ لَكَ كَيۡدًا‌ۖ إِنَّ ٱلشَّيۡطَـٰنَ لِلۡإِنسَـٰنِ عَدُوٌّ۬
>   مُّبِينٌ۬
>
> He said, "O my son, do not relate your vision to your brothers or they
>   will contrive against you a plan. Indeed Satan, to man, is a manifest
>   enemy.

Followed by verse 6:

> وَكَذَٲلِكَ يَجۡتَبِيكَ رَبُّكَ وَيُعَلِّمُكَ مِن تَأۡوِيلِ
>   ٱلۡأَحَادِيثِ وَيُتِمُّ نِعۡمَتَهُ ۥ عَلَيۡكَ  وَعَلَىٰٓ ءَالِ
>   يَعۡقُوبَ كَمَآ أَتَمَّهَا عَلَىٰٓ أَبَوَيۡكَ مِن قَبۡلُ إِبۡرَٲهِيمَ
>   وَإِسۡحَـٰقَ‌ۚ إِنَّ رَبَّكَ عَلِيمٌ حَكِيمٌ۬
>
> And thus will your Lord choose you and teach you the interpretation of
>   narratives and complete His favor upon you and upon the family of
>   Jacob, as He completed it upon your fathers before, Abraham and Isaac.
>   Indeed, your Lord is Knowing and Wise."

Does this mean Yusuf (a.s.) would have received revelation only if he didn't relate his vision to his brothers and if he had related his dream to his brothers, he wouldn't have received the revelation?

Answer (score 2):

No Yaqub AS is giving his interpretation of the dream, not saying that it would happen because he follow his advice.

https://quranx.com/Tafsirs/12.6

Answer (score 0):

We already know that Yusef AS and is brothers were not in a good relationship due to jealousy amongst other things so his father Yaqoub  AS. out of fear for his son advised him not to relay his dream however this is not a command from Allah swt.